# Do Lyft or Uber pick up at San Francisco International airport?

Tags: taxis, sfo, ride-sharing

Are Lyft or Uber allowed to pick up at San Francisco International Airport?  SFO appears to be within Lyft's coverage map, but I know special rules sometimes apply at airports.

I waited till the last minute before a convention to look for car rentals.  I won't let that happen again.

**edited to add**
As noted in the comment below, I was able to get a Lyft ride from SFO to my destination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Uber](https://www.uber.com/cities/san-francisco), it is possible, it even lists suggested prices from the airport to San Francisco and Palo Alto, one more thing:

> Trips to or from SFO on uberX, UberBLACK, or UberSUV are subject to a **$4** airport surcharge and any applicable tolls.

Comment: A fare-checking site that I can't currently find a link to accepted SFO as a starting point and quotes prices for Uber and Lyft.

Comment: Lyft got me to my destination from SFO with no problem.